# Is it possible to upgrade only the http to HttpClient and keep everything the same

Tags: angular, httpclient, upgrade

https://update.angular.io/ and tutorials I came across instructed reader how to upgrade **angular 4+** to **angular 6** and later **HttpModule** to **HttpClientModule**, but not just on **HttpClientModule**.

My question is can we upgrade HttpModule for HttpClientModule without having to upgrade my angular project to 6?

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear what you're asking

Comment: why would you only want to update one module?  I doubt that it would work, considering that the module in question is an internal core module that most likely has dependencies on other core components......

Comment: Thought it is a module, so thought we could just swap one module out for the newer one and come back to finish the upgrade when we have more time.

Comment: What version are you currently using? HttpClientModule was introduced in 4.3, so depending on your current version you may not even need to upgrade

Comment: well the HttpClientModule was introduced with Angular 4.3.0, so perhaps you could just do a minor update and get access to the module?

Comment: I am on 5.2.4.

@Claies Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: on 5.2.4 the module is already available, the answer from @ayoubk is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import HttpClientModule and inject HttpClient service instead of Http.

the only difference is that you do not need to invoke map() to parse out the response data using the extractData() method. This method has been removed, and we simply return the Observable. The default responseType is JSON, and as such, the response data is already parsed for us.

Here's an article that will helps you : https://brianflove.com/2017/07/21/migrating-to-http-client